# Ignore prev value while using "pairwise" using RxStream if filtered or propose different approach

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-reactive-forms

**Task:** In form, user can add points to categories. The number of points depend on user, however overall allowed points to be spend by user is limited. While user inputs value that exceed allowed limit, the input should automatically change to maximum allowed value.

**Example**: Lets say, user added 200 points, 300 points and 100 points, to some categories. Maximum allowed points to spend is limited to 1000 points. While trying to input 600 points to some other category, system should change input value to 400, because it's maximum value that meets limit.

My approach was to subscribe to every input control of points and calculate total price using rxjs filters in such manner:

```
  pointsFormControl.get('points')
          ?.valueChanges
          .pipe(
            startWith(0),
            debounceTime(300),
            pairwise(),
            tap(([prev, next]: [any, any]) => {
              if ((this._totalPoints.getValue() + (next - prev)) > this.maxPoints) {
                subcategoryFormGroup.get('points')?.setValue(prev, { emitEvent: false });
              }
            }),
            filter(([prev, next]: [any, any]) => ((this._totalPoints.getValue() + (next - prev)) < this.maxPoints)),
          )
          .subscribe(
            ([prev, next]: [any, any]) => {
              this._totalPoints.next(this._totalPoints.getValue() + (next - prev));
            }
          );
```

I wanted to use pairwise to calculate difference between previous and current input value, and then use it to calculate new "total points", for that I've used pairwise. Next I am tapping, so if new value exceeds allowed number of points, I am setting it back to prev value (for now, final app should setup maximum allowed number). Then I've planned to use filter to filter all values that after calculation exceeds allowed number of points.

**problem** This approach is not working, because despite filtering value stream still "remembers" previous inproper value. Which means, If user types some huge number, for example: 123123 for the first time, then change same input to something much lower, for example 30, system will calculate difference and set points to negative number.

**my idea** I know, that finite amount of if statements can fix this problem, however I would like to avoid such approach. I feel like answer is simple, but somehow I can't find it. Any idea how to achieve this task would be appreciated.

Mockup App simulating problem: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-cli-qfxmwa?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

**Example is RAW, so it's not supporting improper user input like text or negative numbers, in prod app I've got proper input mask to handle this.**

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish what you want with a validator.  When you create each *subcategoryFormGroup*, create a validator that ensures points haven't been exceeded.  If it has, you can get the prior value from the parent array, since it shouldn't have been updated yet.

```
const categoryFormGroup = this.fb.group({
  name: this.fb.control<string>(category, { nonNullable: true }),
  items: this.fb.array<{ id: string; name: string; points: number }>([]),
});

// MOCKUP SUBCATEGORY BUILD
for (let i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
  const subcategoryFormGroup = this.fb.group({
    id: this.fb.control<string>(`ID-${category}-${i}`),
    name: this.fb.control<string>(`Subcategory Name ${i}`),
    points: this.fb.control<number>(0, {
      updateOn: 'blur', // make sure the update only occurs when the control is blurred.
      validators: (x: AbstractControl<number>) => {
        const points = categoryFormGroup.controls.items
          .getRawValue()
          .reduce((acc, cur) => acc + parseInt((cur?.points as any) ?? 0), 0);
        if (points < this.maxPoints) {
          return null;
        }
        // get old points value.
        x.reset(categoryFormGroup.controls.items.value[i - 1]?.points ?? 0);
        return { maxPointsExceeded: true };
      },
    }),
  });
  // remove all subscriptions.
  // add to parent form groups.
```

I'm sure this can be refined, but this should get you going in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you very much. Although I would rather avoid counting every input value on change, and rather manipulate (add, subtract) value of total_points. However your answer gave me an idea! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem right, I would go for a rxjs-sh solution like the following.

First the problem. It seems to me that you have:

- a stream of values, i.e. the points that the user gives to a category
- a state, represented by the cumulative sum of the points given and the max number of points
- 2 side effects: the points you show for the category and the total points

Now, if all of the above is true, I would proceed like this:

1. First create a function that returns a custom rxjs operator that transforms the stream of values given by the user into a stream of tuples containing 2 values:

- the value that can be effectively given to the category considering the max total points available
- the max total points given up to that moment
  Such a function looks like this

```
function toCategoryPointsAndTotalPoints(maxPoints: number) {
    let totalPoints = 0;
    return pipe(
        map((points: number) => {
            const pointsThatCanBeGivenToCategory = totalPoints + points > maxPoints ? maxPoints - totalPoints : points;
            totalPoints += pointsThatCanBeGivenToCategory;
            return {
                categoryPoints: pointsThatCanBeGivenToCategory,
                totalPoints
            }
        })
    )
}
```

2. Then apply the custom operator to transform the stream of values given by the user into the stream of tuples, and then take the tuples and perform the side effects, like this

```
    pointsFormControl.get('points')
       ?.valueChanges.pipe(
          toCategoryPointsAndTotalPoints(1000),
          tap({
             next: ({ categoryPoints, totalPoints }) => {
                subcategoryFormGroup.get('points')?.setValue(categoryPoints, { emitEvent: false });
                this._totalPoints.next(totalPoints);
             }
          })
       ).subscribe()
```

The following code simulates this behavior (with the Angular side effects part)

const pointsGivenByUser = from([100, 200, 300, 600])

```
function toCategoryPointsAndTotalPoints(maxPoints: number) {
    let totalPoints = 0;
    return pipe(
        map((points: number) => {
            const pointsThatCanBeGivenToCategory = totalPoints + points > maxPoints ? maxPoints - totalPoints : points;
            totalPoints += pointsThatCanBeGivenToCategory;
            return {
                categoryPoints: pointsThatCanBeGivenToCategory,
                totalPoints
            }
        })
    )
}

pointsGivenByUser.pipe(
    toCategoryPointsAndTotalPoints(1000),
    tap({
        next: ({ categoryPoints, totalPoints }) => {
            console.log(`Set Category points to: ${categoryPoints}`)
            console.log(`Set new total points: ${totalPoints}`)
        }
    })
).subscribe()
```